# Limiting / Filtering multivalue fields in Solr

Tags: solr, filter, multivalue

Is there a way to limit, or filter, the returned text of a multivalued field in Solr?  Given the following document structure in Solr:

```
...
<doc>
    <str name="title">example</str>
    <arr name="foo">
        <str>bar1</str>
        <str>bar2</str>
        <str>bar3</str>
        <str>bar4</str>
        <str>bar5</str>
        <str>bar6</str>
    </arr>
</doc>
...
```

I'd like to limit the response to only show 1 of the "foo" values based on a Filter Query request.  So for example, the query:

```
select/?q=example&fq=foo:bar2`
```

I would want a response of:

```
...
<doc>
    <str name="title">example</str>
    <arr name="foo">
        <str>bar2</str>
    </arr>
</doc>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. There is not way to filter the Multivalued Values returned with the response.
You can easily do it at client side though.

If you can use Facet to get the list, you can use [facet.prefix](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.prefix) to limit the values for the field foo returned as facet.

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting this type of answer.  The problem is that "foo" could contain thousands of values which will effect efficiency just on data transfer alone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using dynamic fields if you know the sample space of values for 'foo'? For example:

and then filter on bar_x:true. You would end up using a large number of dynamic fields.

Answer (score -3):

[filter query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters) should work, try below code

`&fq=+foo:"bar2"`